# Определение текущего элемента в обработчике события клавиатуры

Tags: gwt, java

Мне нужно написать обработчик события `KeyUpEvent` - `KeyUpHandler`. Этот обработчик будет привязан к панели, на которой очень много виджетов (поля ввода, текстовые области, чекбоксы, и т.д.). На этой панели по `Enter` будет совершаться некое действие. Но если фокус стоит в текстовой области (`<textarea>`, класс `TextArea`) и она не `read-only`, то действие не должно выполняться, потому что в этом случае должен произойти только перенос строки и всё. Когда фокус в любом другом элементе, прикрепленном к панели, действие должно выполниться.

Вопрос: как в обработчике события `KeyUpEvent` определить, находится ли в данный момент фокус в `textarea`?

Comment: Я не силён в gwt, но мне кажется, что там должно быть что-то вроде isFocused или isActive и т.д

Comment: Такого в GWT нет. Есть только `FocusHandler` и `BlurHandler`, но тогда их придется вешать на все `textarea` и добавить филд, отвечающий за наличие `textarea`.

Comment: может тогда перед выполнения действия проверять где именно находится в фокус

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение получилось таким:

```
    if (e.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) 
    {
      /* Здесь getEventTarget возвращает тот элемент, который сгенерировал событие,
    getCurrentEventTarget() и getRelatedEventTarget() возвращают общую панель
    т.е. тот элемент, на который прикреплен данный обработчик (как и метод getSource)
      */
      EventTarget et = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget();
      Element e = Element.as(et);
      if ("TEXTAREA".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getTagName())) 
      {
        TextAreaElement area = e.<TextAreaElement>cast();
        if (!(area.isReadOnly())) 
        {
          return;
        }
      }
      submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

По идее, [KeyUpHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyUpHandler.html) принимает [KeyUpEvent](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyUpEvent.html), являющийся наследником GwtEvent. А [GwtEvent](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/event/shared/GwtEvent.html) в свою очередь имеет [getSource](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/event/shared/GwtEvent.html#getSource%28%29). Его обычно можно использовать, чтобы опознать источник.

Но... почему бы вам просто не выставлять этот обработчик для указанного поля вместо того, чтобы городить какой-то убогий if ?

Comment: Потому что на панели могут быть разные контролы (заранее неизвестно). И обработка события должна быть именно для панели в целом.

Если `textarea` положить на панель и поставить в неё фокус, то в обработчике метод `getSource` возвратит панель, а не `textarea`.

Comment: Ну так вы когда формируете эти контролы, то вы разве при этом не можете выставлять хэндлеры?

Comment: Хэндлер добавляется к панели. В том месте мы заранее не знаем, что у нас будет на этой панели. А то, что добавляется в панель не знает, о том, что по `enter` данные отправляются на сервер.

Comment: Ему и не надо знать. Ему надо просто сообщить этот хэндлер или фабрику контролов. Так что ответ выше - незачёт, так как является корявым костылём.